# Can't start/deploy Apache Tomcat from Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, apache, tomcat, server

I'm trying to deploy a Java project on an Apache Tomcat server from my test environment (Eclipse Kepler on Linux Ubuntu).

But the Tomcat item in the Servers tab is blocked with the label "Stopping". In the context menu, the Start, Stop, Publish and Clean options are grayed out.

If I click on "Clean Work Directory", there's an alert dialog with the message: "The state of the Tomcat server is in transition or unknown. Try again when the server has reached a stable state". The Ok button is greyed out, only Cancel is available.

I have restarted Eclipse, and the same problem appears. On the System monitor there's no Apache Tomcat program.

Any suggestions on how to solve this issue, other than removing the Tomcat configuration from Eclipse?

Comment: Is the Tomcat server you have setup one that's not also installed as a service on the system?

Comment: Stop Eclipse, move the .metadata directory out of yor workspace directory (dont delete) and start Eclipse again. You will also have to reconfigure your workspace after that, but its worth a try.